# How to use GTK with cv2.namedWindow and cv2.imshow?

Tags: python, opencv, backend, gtk

How can I set the backend to GTK so that when I use `cv2.namedWindow` and `cv2.imshow` to display an image the GTK backend is used?

```
cv2.namedWindow('some_name_for_the_window', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('some_name_for_the_window', the_image_variable)
```

Comment: Is that `the_image_variable` from `the_image_variable  = cv2.imread`?

Answer (score -1):

Backends are ***not*** switchable at runtime. The backend is decided at build time. On Linux, GTK is highly likely to be chosen for official builds. On other platforms, GTK might be available but it won't be the default for an official build.

If you want GTK but you aren't getting it, you'll have to build OpenCV yourself.

There is work to make the GUI backends runtime-switchable but that still requires the *build* to include all the choices for GUI libraries. Even if that work will ever be completed, don't expect official builds to contain more than one backend for any operating system.

In the future, `highgui` is supposed to depend on nothing but OpenGL/Vulkan, to present a consistent view across platforms.